# JQuery header moves position when clicking ios "previous" & "Next" buttons

Tags: ios, jquery-mobile, cordova

I have built an app using JQuery 1.1.0 and Phonegap. The problem I have now is that when I input text into a field and I tap on the ios keypad's 'previous" & "Next" buttons, the header moves -momentarily- from its fixed position and appears at different positions on the page. I must add that it is also inconsistent as it doesn't do this on other pages. The headers are marked as fixed, so I have no idea why they would sometimes appear and sometimes not.

This part of a multipage is an example of a page that works 'most of the time', but sometimes the header would slide in an out of the screen as I navigate between fields.

```
<div data-role="page" id="accident_detail" data-theme="f">
    <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed">
        <a href="#accident_insured" data-icon="arrow-l" data-direction="reverse" data-iconpos="notext"></a>
        <h1>Description</h1>
        <a href="#accident_vehicle" data-icon="arrow-r" data-iconpos="notext"></a>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content">
        <label for="incident_date">Date of Incident:</label>
        <input type="date" name="incident_date" id="incident_date" value="" class="required"/>
        <label for="incident_description">Description of Incident:</label>
        <textarea cols="40" rows="8" name="incident_description" id="incident_description" class="required"></textarea>
        <label for="accident_damage">Damage description:</label>
        <textarea cols="40" rows="8" name="accident_damage" id="accident_damage"></textarea>
        <label for="location_street">Street:</label>
        <input type="text" name="location_street" id="location_street" value="" class="required"/>
        <label for="location_city">City:</label>
        <input type="text" name="location_city" id="location_city" value="" class="required"/></div>
    <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed" class="ui-btn-right" style="min-height:42px;">
        <a href="#accident_menu" data-icon="arrow-l" data-direction="reverse" data-iconpos="left"
           style="margin-left: 10px; margin-top: 5px">Done</a>
        <a href="index.html" rel="external" data-icon="home" data-direction="reverse" data-iconpos="notext"
           style="float: right; margin-right: 10px; margin-top: 5px"></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: i'm facing a similar situation, any updates on this post?

Comment: I managed to work around this problem by removing the data-position="fixed" attribute from the "header" in the HTML and using a CSS "hack" instead. .header {
    position:fixed;
    z-index:10;
    top:0;
    width:100%;

Answer (score 0):

YOU CAN TRY THIS..

```
<div data-role="page" id="myPage">
<div data-role="header" data-position="fixed" data-tap-toggle="false">
    <a data-icon="back" data-transition="none">Back</a>
    <h1>PAGE TITLE</h1>
</div>
</div>
```